# If WebClient adds a cert to request.ClientCertificates will the cert be found at context.Request.ClientCertificate in the web app?

Tags: webclient, client-certificates, iis-10

My client-side code uses `WebClient` and appends a certificate to `ClientCertificates`:

```
 protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address); 
            var x509 = GetMyCert();  // see note
            request.ClientCertificates.Add( x509  );
            return request;
        }
```

NOTE: I've checked in the debugger and  variable `x509` does indeed contain a valid certificate object at this point in the code.

Is that not the right way to add the cert to the HttpWebRequest so that it is available to the web app?

Server-side, the certificate isn't showing up in the `ProcessRequest` method of the `IHttpHandler`:

```
         context.Response.Clear();
         // set some Response caching parameters here <snip>

         HttpClientCertificate cert = context.Request.ClientCertificate;
         if (cert.IsPresent)
          {
             Hooray();
          }
          else
         {
             BooHoo();   // we are here
         }
```

The `web.config`  is set to accept a client certificate:

```
 <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert" />
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
```

Is the web app configuration incomplete?

P.S. If I add the callback to the overridden `GetWebRequest` method:

```
 System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
        delegate (Object obj, X509Certificate X509certificate, X509Chain chain, 
        System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors errors)
    {
        return (errors == SslPolicyErrors.None);                
    };
```

`errors` is `SslPolicyErrors.None` and the callback returns `true`.  But I have not created any policy on the server, to my knowledge, unless there's a default of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the certificate is not showing up in the HttpContext is the certificate authentication hasn’t been established yet between the client-side and the server-side.
Simply speaking, when the web application is hosted in IIS, we disable other authentication modes in IIS and enable the IIS client certificate mapping authentication. the server requires a client certificate when the client tries to access the website/service.
[image]
[image]
[image]
Subsequently, the below function method will have a returned value.

```
public ActionResult About()
    {
        var result = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate;
        ViewBag.Message = result.Subject+result.ServerSubject;
        return View();
}
```

[image]
Please refer to the documentation for what is IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authentication and how to implement it in IIS.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/iisclientcertificatemappingauthentication/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/configure-many-to-one-client-mappings
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configuring-one-to-one-client-certificate-mappings
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: I see. I did not realize that it is not possible to have Windows Authentication and also a negociable (not required) Client Certificate as an additional security measure. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: How would we implement this security policy? "Domain user X, you are authorized to access this intranet web app; however, if you wish to access the most sensitive data, you must not be using a workstation in a conference room or training room."  The PCs in the conference room and training room would not have had the client certificate installed into their local machine store.